# What relevence does LAMP, WAMP, etc. have to a web designer?

Tags: wamp, lamp

Another developer asked me whether I work with LAMP or WAMP, and I didn't know what to say. My simplified process thus far has been:

1. Make site (PHP and the usual)
2. Upload to client's server via FileZilla
3. See site.

For PHP testing, I've just been uploading it to a test folder on the server. I hear you can use Apache locally to test PHP. So using Windows, would running this be running WAMP?

Basically, everywhere I go I hear about LAMP and WAMP used by web developers, and I've never had to worry about it. Have I been doing something horribly wrong all this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*AMP is a acronym for Apache MySQL PHP.

The starting letter is kind of your platform: Linux/Windows/Mamp. So if you are a Mac user, you probably use Mamp, or Wamp for windows and... you get the idea.

As a designer doesn't really mater what are you using. (actually not even as programmer if your code works well on client server)